# Ionic - how do I change the entire header background-color?

Tags: css, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm unable to get the entire header color change. I manage to change the color of the white header but not the black header where time is shown. I understand that's out of Ionic and is part of the Android but I've seen many Apps which changes the color.

[image]
Any help would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Ionic Native status bar:
   
`npm install @ionic-native/core --save
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar
npm install --save @ionic-native/status-bar`

Add Plugins to Your App's Module

`
    ...

```
import { StatusBar} from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

...

@NgModule({
  ...

  providers: [
    ...
    StatusBar
    ...
  ]
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

`

And then use it in your rootPage:

`

```
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

constructor(private statusBar: StatusBar) { }

...

// let status bar overlay webview
this.statusBar.overlaysWebView(true);

// set status bar to white
this.statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#ffffff');
```

`

For more information : https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/status-bar/

Comment: I have done this too but there's no change. Do I have to create a .apk to see the changes and not on preview on Chrome?

Comment: This will not work in your browser since you're using cordova.

Answer (score 1):

.scss

```css
.toolbar-background{
  background-color:#7e6cfc;
}
```